# Schema.org snippet for thumbs up-down reviews

Tags: seo, google-search, microdata

I'm deep into the Schema.org meta-tags implementation for the reviews on my website and I'd love to know how do you think I should implement it when I have Positive-Negative reviews as opposed to star ratings.  I couldn't find a site that had this with schema tags for reference.  Fiverr used to have thumbs up/down, but recently changed to star rating.

On our services marketplace we allow users to review the providers they worked with and ask them for a positive-negative review - thumbs up/down with an additional open text area.

I thought about adding a schema.org meta-tags like this:

Lets assume one of our providers got two reviews, one is positive and the second is negative. So, first I thought about adding an aggregateReview meta-tag on top, just like this:

```
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
  <meta itemprop="ratingValue"content="1" />
  <meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="2" />
</div>
```

And also add a meta-tag for any review, like this:

```
<div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
  <span class="author-name">
    <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2014-02-02">
    <span class="datePublished">Two days ago</span> by
    <span itemprop="author">Kareem Abdul-Jabbar</span>
  </span>

  <div class="review-body" itemprop="reviewBody">
    Joe is a great guy, I'd recommend him to my friends.
  </div>
</div>
```

Does that make sense?

Has anyone had the chance to implement a schema.org meta tags for this kind of situation or familiar with a website who does it that way?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Cant you do them on a review scale of 2 where 1 = thumbs down and two equals thumbs up?

Comment: @Frank, Do you think it would be more convenient to do it in scales of 0-1 or 1-2?

Comment: @itamyau you know I thought about this and the only issue i see is that your aggregate ratings may be off.   On a scale of 2 stars, one star still looks like it has a positive value, where a thumbs up and thumbs down system a thumbs up = +1 and thumbs down = -1.   There is no schema for thumbs up and down ratings, so I dont think you have much choice.  And even when the schema exists later, its going to take google a pretty long time to use it as a rich snippet, where they actually show the ratings right now.

Comment: Thanks @Frank for your help, what do you suggest me to do? Do you think changing the thumbs up/down scale to 1-2 will fix it?

Comment: I dont know if it will fix it.  If you had it where scale 1 = thumbs down, and scale 5 = thumbs up, then you could possibly show up with stars under your search results (looks like reviews).  Again, google doesnt have the thumbs up thumbs down (neither does schema) so you would be hacking things.